# Reading InnerHTML from returned form object?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps

A Simple question. Hope someone can help reply me this time.

```
Page.html:
<form id="xForm" name="xForm" onsubmit="submitData(this);">
...
  <span id="xSpan" name="xSpan" hidden="true">
    [Content Part]
  </span>
...
</form>

<script>
function submitData(xForm){
   google.script.run.zConvertALL(xForm);
}
</script>


Code.gs
function zConvertALL(xForm){
  var vSpan = xForm.xSpan.innerHTML;  //This line is not okay.
  ....
}
```

About above problematic line, I am not sure if error is by xSpan (undefined? according to error report). But by xForm.xElement, I can read the value of xElement successfully. So innerHTML should be the problem. It can't be used in Server's side, right? Any alternative Javascript function for me to read the above [Content Part] ?

Answer (score 0):

Change "myForm" to "xForm", like this you define the argument of the method as named "xForm" and you define it. In your code xForm is undefined in the function called when the form is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass html elements to server-side functions, only javascript values. This is true for any framework and web language, not just apps script. Please take a look at the htmlService docs.
You are missing client+side js to extract what you need from the dom and pass it as parameters.

Comment: Hello Zig Mandel, thanks for your reply. I have read htmlService docs for several times. I don't want to do the extraction in Client-side JScript. Although innerHTML don't work, I know extracting that part is still possible in Server side, since whole "form" has already been successfully returned to server through xForm. I just need another command. I guess jQuery can do it, but I am not familiar with it. If you know the both commands of JScript and jQuery, please help give me a simple demo.

Comment: at most you will receive a javascript map of key/value pairs, you will NOT receive DOM/jquery/html elements.